# Moving Windows 10 bootloader to another drive

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, ssd, bootloader, efi

Here's the situation.  I have 2 SSD hard drives in my system, a 128GB and 500GB.  Currently, my partition structure is this:

500GB - Ubuntu 16.04 Install

```
Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624   2050047    999424   488M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2050048 976771071 974721024 464.8G Linux LVM
```

128GB - Windows 10 Install

```
Device     Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 250068991 250066944 119.2G Microsoft basic data
```

My situation is that I'm running out of space on my Windows 10 drive.  What I want to do is use Clonezilla to clone my Windows 10 drive over to my 500GB drive.  I'm fine with loosing my Ubuntu drive and installing from scratch onto the 128GB drive later, I have everything backed up.

My one concern is the EFI partition on the Linux drive, I'm pretty sure if I do a device-device transfer with Clonezilla, my Windows install will no longer boot due to the now missing EFI directory, is this a correct assumption?  I do see within /boot/efi a directory for Microsoft, but I'm unsure on how to "fix" the Windows drive after the imaging is done.